# db.collection.group - display other attributes too

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have objects such as:

```
{
 foo: "A",
 bar: "Alpha"
},
{
 foo: "A",
 bar: "Alphabet"
},
{
 foo: "B",
 bar: "Beta"
}
```

I am using this query:

```
db.collectionName.group({
  key:{foo: 1}, 
  reduce: function(curr, result){}, 
  initial: {}
})
```

to group them by `foo` field. It returns object such as:

```
{
  foo: "A"
},
{
  foo: "B"
}
```

however I want them to display such as:

```
{
 foo: "A",
 bar: "Alpha"
},
{
 foo: "B",
 bar: "Beta"
}
```

It doesn't really matter which value will be shown in `bar`, but I need any value. If I would also include `bar` for the `key` param to the `group` attribute object, I would get many duplicates, but I only need uniques by `foo` field, while `bar` can be value from any of objects that match `foo` group.

Comment: Use group aggregation. db.colection.aggregate(    [ {        $group:          {            _id: "$foo",            bar: { $first: "$bar" }          }      }    ] )

Comment: Exactly use aggregate function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`db.collection.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** with the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage as:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$foo",
            "bar": { "$first": "$bar" }
        }
    }
])
```

---

To get the exact output, push another **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage to format your final output as:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$foo",
            "bar": { "$first": "$bar" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "foo": "$_id",
            "bar": 1
        }
    }
])
```